# ARDUİNO MODBUS TCP CONNECTİON

Tags: communication, ethernet, modbus, enc28j60

I am trying to communicate with PC by using modbus TCP communicate. When I use this code I can't communicate. Dou you know guys what is the problem? My ethernet Module is working I know that because I can ping it when I use different code from EtherCard.h library. But when I try to use Ethernet and Modbus library I can't communicate. I can't ping it.

```
#include <ModbusIP.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Modbus.h>

int setPoint;zz
const int setPoint_IR = 100;

ModbusIP mb;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  byte mac [] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
  byte ip [] = {10, 0, 58, 37};
  mb.config (mac, ip);

  mb.addIreg(setPoint_IR);

}

void loop() {
  mb.task();
  setPoint = analogRead(A0);
  mb.Ireg(setPoint_IR, setPoint);
}

void DisplaySetPointValues(){
  String Printstr;
  Printstr = "Set point values = " + String(setPoint);
  Serial.println(Printstr);
}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use my EthernetENC library

Comment: remove the 3.3V wire

Comment: Ethernet.h is for W5100 based cards (Arduino Ethernet shields). You cannot use it for an ENC28J60.

Comment: Thank you so much guys.